# How can i take a picture using AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, avcapturesession

I have a code that set a camera view as a subview, what i need is when i click a button it takes a picture from this `AVCaptureSession` and save it in to the photo library, how can i achive this?

Heres is my code:

> AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
>           AVCaptureOutput *output = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
>           [session addOutput:output];
>
> ```
>     //Setup camera input
>     NSArray *possibleDevices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
>     //You could check for front or back camera here, but for simplicity just grab the first device
>     AVCaptureDevice *device = [possibleDevices objectAtIndex:1];
>
>     NSError *error = nil;
>     // create an input and add it to the session
>     AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error]; //Handle errors
>
>     //set the session preset
>     session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium; //Or other preset supported by the input device
>     [session addInput:input];
>
>     AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:session];
>
>     previewLayer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
>     //Set the preview layer frame
>     previewLayer.frame = CGRectMake(45, 55, 512, 387);
>     //Now you can add this layer to a view of your view controller
>     [self.cameraPlace.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];
>     [session startRunning];
> ```

Comment: There are n number of samples and description links available on internet. Before asking question Browse it, some of the related links, http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1297 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264749/capturing-images-from-avcapturesession http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924299/ios-capturing-image-using-avframework http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312832/avcapturesession-specify-resolution-and-quality-of-captured-images-obj-c-iphone

Comment: possible duplicate of [ios capturing image using AVFramework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924299/ios-capturing-image-using-avframework)